# Increase maximum memory limit in own install of OpenStreetMap's Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

For my specific purpose, I need to alter Overpass API's definition of an `area` to include all buildings, whether or not they have names (so `is_in()` will return these buildings when requested).

To achieve this, I've installed a local copy of the API with 3 specific countries and have modified the os3m script that generates areas to suite my definition -- so far, so good.

Obviously this script will require more memory than the default one as it is handling a **lot** more `ways`. The machine I'm running on has `16GB of RAM`. If I specify `2GB` or less for the script (i.e. `element-limit="2073741824"`) then it will run out of memory, but specifying any more (even by 100MB) will **always** result in the error:

> Dispatcher_Client::request_read_and_idx::timeout

after just a few seconds.

The question is, how I can tell the Overpass API/dispatchers that using more than `2GB` is perfectly fine, and in fact, allow it to allocate up to `~15GB` for this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to increase both values for `total_available_space` in settings.cc (currently at 4GB) and recompile Overpass API from source.

AFAIK nobody has tried to process a huge number of buildings via areas before, so be prepared for further issues. The [Overpass API developer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Developers_.2F_System_Administrators) list may be a good place to discuss this, also to get Roland's attention (Overpass API developer/maintainer), as he's not around on stackoverflow.

Comment: I actually gave up in the end and split the query into multiple overlapping bounding boxes. While I'm only using 3 countries, it's actually gone surprisingly smoothly even with the extra areas (and running each query don't seem to overwrite the areas generated in the previous one), so it's not an ideal solution but does work.

That said, I'll try increasing the value you said and recompiling. Will report back once I've done it!

Comment: Right. You can split the query into multiple bboxes, different queries won't overwrite each other's results. That's why you can also run area updates in delta mode, see https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/141

Comment: I've found some time and done as you suggested by changing total_available_space then rebuilding, and can confirm that it's now accepting my query requesting 10GB of RAM. This will make it a lot easier if I ever need to generate areas from scratch again, and hopefully will help someone else. Thanks a lot!